# Quickly search all elements in two lists

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, search, computer-science

Say I have two large lists, list_of_A_objects which contains objects of class A, and list _of_B_objects which contains objects of class B.

They both have string members.

I want to be able to search through all the elements in the two lists and if the string member of an A object is a sub-string of the string member of a B object I want it to do something.

What I've got below is fine if the lists are quite small, but if the lists are large it can take a long time.

Is there a way to make this faster. I've been thinking about using dictionaries in some way because they have fast lookups but I cant figure it out.

This is what I have so far.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.string = x

class B:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.string = x

list_of_A_objects = get_large_list_of_A_objects()

list_of_B_objects = get_large_list_of_B_objects() 


for A_object in list_of_A_objects:
    for B_Object in list_of_B_objects:
        if A_object.string in B_Object.string:
            do_something()
```

Comment: The time it takes to do_something isn't what I'm concerned about. The code above is a simplified example of my problem. In my real problem as one list gets bigger, the other one does too, so I get an n^2 time order sort of thing happening as one of the lists increase in size.

Comment: I asked as there is a big difference between finding the first match and doing something or looking for multiple matches, I don't think a set or a dict can help either as you are looking for a substring

Comment: OK I see what you mean. It would need to search for multiple matches. Thanks

Comment: Are there are any constraints on the strings? If they are general strings, then it seems like it would be hard to do better than quadratic complexity, but if they are special there might be some tricks.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is create a single string from the B objects. While building that, you also create a list of indexes, so you know the index of each string in the larger string. See the code below.

Note that I'm not a python programmer, so you'll have to interpret my pseudo-code.

```
BStrings = ""
list_of_Indexes = new list of int
for B_object in list_of_B_objects
    list_of_Indexes.Add(length of BStrings)
    BStrings = BStrings + B_Object.string + newline
```

Now, you can search the BStrings string for each A_object. If the string is found, the function returns the index of where it was found in the string. You can then binary search the list_of_indexes to determine which B_object contains that string.

This doesn't really change the complexity of the operation (it's still MxN, where M is the number of objects in the A list, and N is the length of the B list), but searching a single string for substrings will be faster than looping over the B list because it avoids the overhead of setting up the search.

If even that is too slow, then you'll want to use something like the [Aho-Corasick string matching algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm). There's probably a decent Python implementation available.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer, I will have a think about this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a python implementation using a dictionary. First convert one of the lists into a indexed by its object's strings

```
a_map = {}

for A_object in list_of_A_objects:
    a_map[A_object.string] = A_object
```

Then for each object in the other list, check whether the object's string exists in the dictionary (in constant time), and if so do_something

```
for B_object in list_of_B_objects:
    if B_object.string in a_map:
        do_something(a_map[B_object.string])
```

This assumes that each A_object has a unique string. If that's not the case then you can make the values of a_map an array of objects instead of a single object.